# How to call a function with a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, struct

I am working with eclipse.
i want to save name in the struct something in a different copy than the original copy that i recieved as a parameter , i did this but it is wrong because of the free thing .. but i have to do free inside of this function i guess .. when i try to run my program in eclipde it just tells me i have something wrong and the same thing happens when i tru to run the debbug .. i know for sure the problem is with free because if i deleate free everything works perfectly !
I have a `struct` for example:

```
    typedef struct Ssomething {
      int num;
      char *name;
      Level level;
    } Something;
Result copy_name(Something *something, char *name) {
  if (something == NULL || name == NULL) {
    return NULL_PARAMETER;
  }
  char *name2 = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
  if (name2 == NULL) {
    return MEMORY_PROBLEM;
  }
  memcpy(name2, name, strlen(name) + 1);
  something->name = name2;
  free(name2);
  return OK;
}
```

i updated the question to where the problem actuallt is ! still didn't figure the solution :\

Comment: Saying that you get an error, then not saying what the error is is very unhelpful.

Comment: @RH6 ..but it is `typedef`ed to `Something`

Comment: @LPs I know, it was just bugging me.

Comment: yes the stuct name is Ssomething and i typedef the struct to Something so i  when i want to use the struct i just call it by the name Something

Comment: Now is probably a good time to use a debugger. This bug was fairly trivial to find. Would have taken you 10 seconds.

Comment: Carcigenicate i just want to know in the end when i call the function is that the way we do it ? because as i saied the eclipse just suddenly stop working when i try to run this so i have no idea where is the problem! i feel that the mistake is in the main function !

Answer (score 3):

```
if(something==NULL || name==NULL)  
{
  return NULL_PARAMETER;
}
```

Then you pass NULL to `name` here: `init_something(something, 11, NULL, Hard);`. So your function does nothing and you don't check your own error code.

Meaning that `something->num` does not get initialized and you call `printf("%d",something->num);`.

Comment: @lia _You_ made these functions and invented these error codes. Why ask me?

Answer (score 2):

your `copy_name` at first seems to do everything right but at the end it `free`s the  allocated memory and also therefore invalidates the `something->name` pointer and reading from this address causes a crash.

You have to keep the memory and ensure that it is `free`d when the `Something`-object is not required anymore.

Additional hints:

- you may add some `const`s to your code - at least at the name input pointers
- use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` for copying strings
- if there are any return error codes: Do check them! 
   (in this case you are ignoring your own return vaulues that would say `NULL_PARAMETER`)

Comment: i didn't get why free is wrong here !? i want the *name to get the name i recieved in the function

Comment: like how i can get name to be saved in something struct in a different copy from the original name that i recieved from the function :\

Comment: you aquire memory to hold the string, you cpy the string to this memory and you copy the pointer to this memory to the struct. So freeing the memory leaves a dangling pointer in struct.

Comment: yeah free was defently the problem ! after i deleated free i worked but i am trieng to change  the function copy_name because as requested i must free the memory in this function

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong here.

1. You are freeing memory that is being referenced somewhere else.

   ```
    memcpy(name2, name , strlen(name)+1);
    something->name= name2;
    free(name2);
   ```

   You're setting the structs name property equal to another pointer, and then freeing the memory that reference is being made to, this is called a [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) If you want to copy the values from name2 into name, just use strcpy like so

`strcpy(something->name, name2);`

You also didn't allocate any memory for your name property, so before you copy name2 into name, you need to do that.

2. You're calling your init_something function and then checking for properties that are possibly null

In this case you yourself passed in `null` as a parameter for your char* name parameter, which will always cause the function to return `NULL_PARAMETER` , which makes the rest of the function not be evaluated, so your `num` property is not set, so trying to reference it in your `printf` most likely causes your program to crash. If you want to try to retrieve that property you're gonna need to use conditional logic to make sure your struct's properties have been set.

```
if (init_something(something, 11, NULL, Hard) != NULL_PARAMETER)
    printf("%d", something->num);
else
    printf("Properties not set");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *name2 = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
if (name2 == NULL) {
  return MEMORY_PROBLEM;
}
memcpy(name2, name, strlen(name) + 1);
something->name = name2;
free(name2);  // BZZT.  Here's your problem.
```

You allocate memory for your name, copy the name to it, *and then free that memory*.  After the call to `free`, `something->name` becomes an *invalid* pointer, so accessing it later on leads to undefined behavior (in this case, a segfault).

You really don't need the separate `name2` object - that can be reduced to

```
something->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
if ( something->name )
  strcpy( something->name, name );
```

Don't free `something->name` until you know you're done with it.  You will want to `free` it *before* `free`ing `something`:

```
free( something->name );
free( something );
```

**EDIT**

It may be helpful to provide your own allocation and deallocation functions, such as

```
Something *newSomething( int num, const char *name, Level l )
{
  Something *s = malloc( sizeof *s );
  if ( s )
  {
    s->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
    if ( s->name )
      strcpy( s->name, name );
    s->num = num;
    s->level = l;
  }
  return s;
}

void freeSomething( Something **s )
{
  if ( *s )
  {
    if ( (*s)->name )
    {
      free( (*s)->name );
    }
    free( *s );
    *s = NULL;
  }
}
```

Granted, this only works for instances of `Something` that are allocated dynamically; you'll have to do something different for instances that are allocated as `auto` or `static`.

Comment: i must free the malloc in this function because the tests everytime changes because let say someine wantes to write tests to my functions he won't check what i did in the function thats why he won't free it ! i understand that i did something very wrong and i am trieng to think of a different solution !

Comment: like how i can get name to be saved in something struct in a different copy from the original name that i recieved from the function

Comment: @lia: You have two choices - make `name` an array of some fixed size in the `struct` definition, or make it clear that the caller is responsible for freeing any memory allocated by this function.  You can't `free` the memory allocated in this function and have it be usable to anyone else after the function exits.